# Sending POST data with cURL and PHP to retrieve airlines information

Tags: php, post, curl, web-scraping

I always use PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser to make web scraping scripts, but this time I need to use cURL because the form uses POST and I don't know why my script it's not working.

I'm using Burp Proxy to get the all POST information.

I want to make queries using cURL.

This is function and I will take http://flyfirstnation.com as example:

```
<?php

function curl_get_contents($url)
{
  $curl_moteur = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl_moteur, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($curl_moteur, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt ($curl_moteur, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt ($curl_moteur, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"FormData":{"Origin":["LOS"],"VarsSessionID":"","Destination":["ABV"],"DepartureDate":["24-Jan-2014"],"ReturnDate":["28-Jan-2014","28-Jan-2014"],"Adults":"1","Children":"0","Seniors":0,"Students":0,"Infants":"0","Youths":0,"Teachers":0,"SeatedInfants":0,"EVoucher":"","SearchUser":"PUBLIC"},"IsMMBChangeFlightMode":false}');


  curl_setopt($curl_moteur,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');

  curl_setopt($curl_moteur, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  $web = curl_exec($curl_moteur);
  curl_close($curl_moteur);
  return $web;
}


echo curl_get_contents('reservations.flyfirstnation.com');

?>
```

And this is the error message I'm getting:

> The page cannot be displayed
>
> The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid
>   method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt access. Please try the
>   following:
>
> Contact the Web site administrator if you believe that this request
>   should be allowed. Make sure that the Web site address displayed in
>   the address bar of your browser is spelled and formatted correctly.
>   HTTP Error 405 - The HTTP verb used to access this page is not
>   allowed. Internet Information Services (IIS)
>
> Technical Information (for support personnel)
>
> Go to Microsoft Product Support Services and perform a title search
>   for the words HTTP and 405. Open IIS Help, which is accessible in IIS
>   Manager (inetmgr), and search for topics titled Setting Application
>   Mappings, Securing Your Site with Web Site Permissions, and About
>   Custom Error Messages.

Comment: Define "it's not working".

Comment: "It's not working" isn't helpful. What does it do? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: I just want to see in the website in my browser using cURL.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a problem in CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS value, it has to be a key-value PHP array like this:

```
$postFields = array(
    "FormData" => array(
        "Origin" => array(
        ...
        )
    )
);
```

more info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: you can add the POST parameters like that (using an array) or entering the whole string, both methods are OK.

Comment: yes but if you enter a string, it must be an urlencoded string such as var1=key1&var2=key2, not a json encoded string

Answer (score 0):

You are posting JSON data during the POST operation. You need to specify this with HTTP Header.

```
curl_setopt($curl_moteur, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json") );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go to `reservations.flyfirstnation.com` with a GET (e.g. in a browser), you get immediately redirected to a site that uses `http://reservations.flyfirstnation.com/VARS/Public/FlightSelect.aspx` to POST its data to. You try to POST to `reservations.flyfirstnation.com`, which is not allowed (HTTP error 405).

If you POST your data like this, it'll work:

```
echo curl_get_contents('http://reservations.flyfirstnation.com/VARS/Public/FlightSelect.aspx');
```

I tried it, and it works (that is, I get an HTML document, no idea if it's the right one).

Comment: no, what I want to see is the page with prices of the flights. Thanks

Comment: They also use a cookie with a session ID.